# problema al usar join en laravel

Tags: laravel, join

Colegas tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$count_tareas = DB::table('personas')
                    ->join('soluciones', 'soluciones.user_id', '=', 'personas.id')
                    ->join('participantes', 'participantes.persona_id', '=', 'personas.id')
                    ->where('soluciones.user_id', '=', $this->id)
                    ->orwhere('participantes.persona_id', '=', $this->id)
                    ->select('soluciones.*', 'participantes.*')
                    ->get();
```

Estoy realizando un join con dos tablas para saber si una persona se encuentra en la tabla `soluciones` y en la tabla `participantes` para así obtener la cantidad de veces que esa persona aparece tanto en `soluciones` como en `participantes`. Después lo intento muestro en pantalla de la siguiente forma: `return count($count_tareas)` pero me el resultado es cero. En la base de datos revise y si aparece el usuario.

Esta es las tablas como esta conformadas:

[image: Relacion de las tablas]

Estuve revisando el código y me percate que cuando quito uno de los join, si funciona la consulta y me devuelve el valor que estoy esperando.

De esta forma:

```
$count_tareas = DB::table('personas')
                    ->join('soluciones', 'soluciones.user_id', '=', 'personas.id')

                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as Hours'))
                    ->where('soluciones.user_id', '=', $this->id)
                    
                    ->get();
```

Pero porque cuando le pongo los dos join no funciona, donde puede estar el problema. sldos

Comment: me devuelve cero

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de tus tablas?

Comment: ya puse una imagen con la estructura de tablas

Comment: si quito soluciones y dejo el join de participantes funciona perfectamente. Los dos a la vez en la consulta es lo que me esta dando el problema al parecer

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error está en los where, suponiendo que $this es una instancia del modelo Persona, deberías preguntar por el id de la tabla personas en vez de preguntar por las otras dos tablas. Quedaría algo mas o menos así:

```
$count_tareas = DB::table('personas')
                    ->join('soluciones', 'soluciones.user_id', '=', 'personas.id')
                    ->join('participantes', 'participantes.persona_id', '=', 'personas.id')
                    ->where('personas.id', '=', $this->id)
                    ->select('soluciones.*', 'participantes.*')

                    ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias por su oportuna respuesta pero si quito el where debe darme todo lo que esta en las tablas y no me envía nada. Ahora si quito uno de los join funciona perfectamente. Que pudiera ser esto

Comment: Probaste colocar el where como coloqué en el ejemplo?

Comment: si lo probe y no me funciona, el tema esta que cuando quito uno de los join enseguida me funciona el codigo